# What does the famous bias-variance figure actually represent?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, variance, bias, bias-variance-tradeoff

Below figure is generally used to explain bias-variance tradeoff.
But something which is not clear and not explained anywhere is: What does the dots represent ?
Do they represent:
1. predictions on same test observation by same model (but trained on different datasets ?)
2. or predictions on multiple test observations by same model (trained on just a single dataset) ?
3. or something else altogether ?

[image: Bias Variance trade off]

Comment: The center of the red dot is the true value of what you are trying to predict, and the blue dots are your actual predictions.   Everything else is irrelevant detail, since this diagram is meant to illustrate the concepts of high and low bias and variance without reference to any particular real-world problem (or class thereof.)

Comment: @jbowman, so does each blue dot represent prediction for the same test sample or is it that each blue dot represents predictions for different samples by the same model ?

Comment: It doesn't matter; either or both.